# Need to copy large directory structure, re-mounting and re-trying in case of I/O error

Tags: mount, external-hdd, cp

I have an external hard drive which works for several minutes at a time, and then un-mounts itself. I am trying to copy 300GB of data off of it. I'd like a program that works like Dolphin (the Kubuntu file manager) for copying, but when a file fails to copy I want it to re-mount the drive and repeat the attempt to copy the file. I can imagine writing a script for this myself in bash or python, but was wondering if there's already a utility out there which tries really hard to copy things!

Answer (score 1):

First, why is it un-mounting itself? I've seen filesystems with errors get remounted as read-only before... is it a filesystem error, or does the hard drive actually power itself down or "reset"? Look in your logs and check (`/var/log/syslog` or `dmesg` should help).

If it's a filesystem error, then mounting it as read-only (`mount -o ro ...`) should keep it mounted, since you won't be writing anything to it. Fixing the filesystem errors  might fix it, with a `fsck` tool, or if it's NTFS it may need a windows `chkdsk` to fix some errors. Unless there are hardware errors....

---

If there *are* hardware errors causing it to be un-mounted, then it's possible your drive is failing, and repeatedly mounting it read-write (`rw`) could be making it worse, possibly overwriting the data you want to save. Then data recovery could be needed, like `gddrescue` (GNU ddrescue) to image what you can read from the drive, then work on the image, with `testdisk` tools.

Comment: I think the drive is losing power and restarting. Some sort of electrical problem, I imagine. The data's not critical, but it'd be nice to have. Was hoping not to have to go into full-on data recovery mode. It's FAT32. Mounting ro is wise, forgot to do that, thanks.

Comment: External drives can be tricky, if you've got a desktop (or a laptop & live dvd/usb even) you could take the drive out of the enclosure & plug it in directly, might work better? And no worries about USB problems (often causes headaches & mysterious errors for me)

Comment: Yeah... I'd been thinking about that too. Not to hard to scrounge an old desktop from somewhere I guess.